# How to find which files have not changed since commit?

Tags: git

In git, how can one find out which files in directory have NOT changed since some commit?

Comment: use command `git status`

Comment: that works for one file, but how to find out all files that have not changed since a commit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO a far easier way to generate your list would be the following command chain:

```
git ls-files --full-name | grep -v "$(git diff --name-only <REF>)"
```

Where `<REF>` is the hash of the commit from which you want the unchanged files since.

---

`git ls-files` list, as you could expect, all versioned files and then you grep all files which aren't in the list of changed files since the specified commit.

Comment: Note that this requires you to be in the top level of the repository, since `git ls-files` will only list files in and below the working directory.

Comment: If you want to compare to your working directory, simply remove "<REF>".

Answer (score 3):

Use `git diff --name-only $REV` to get the list of files that have changed.  Use `git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ls-tree -r HEAD  --name-only` to get the list of all files.  Use `grep` to separate the sets:

```
git diff ${REV?must specify a REV} --name-only > /tmp/list
git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ls-tree -r HEAD  --name-only |
     grep -f /tmp/list -v
```

Prior to executing those commands, you'll need to specify a rev in the variable REV.  eg, `REV=HEAD~6` or `REV=branch-name~~`

Comment: Ha! you should have just said 'learn to use git' :) I was looking for more simpler approach but I guess this is not so common task.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `git ls-files`? Then a list could be generated with `git ls-files | grep -v $(git diff --name-only <REF>)`.

Comment: No reason, I'm just more familiar with ls-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Note the suggested solutions treat file *deletion* after a commit as a change after it.

Also on a large git repo, the suggested one-liners did not work for me with the thrown error: `grep: Argument list too long`.

So, I had to work with files:

```
$ git ls-files --full-name | sort > all.git
$ git diff --name-only <REF> | sort > recent.change
$ comm -12 all.git recent > recent.change.not.deleted
$ comm -13 all.git recent.change.not.deleted
```

`comm` is [a linux utility](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) that shows common and unique lines in two files. Hopefully similar utilities exist for other platforms.