# How to count number of lines written before a given date with Git

Tags: git

I have a codebase for which I need to find out the number of lines still present today that were written before a given date (1 January 2018).

Is there a way to do this? 
I've looked into comparing the lines changed between a commit made that day and our last commit, but it also displays the lines/files deleted.

Comment: Can you share what you already tried, even if it doesn't work yet? You might not be too far from it.

Comment: take a look on answer given by @Steffen G in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211955/git-number-of-lines-not-changed-since-specific-commit?answertab=votes#tab-top . I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two commit IDs you can do:

```
git diff --shortstat <COMMIT_ID> <SECOND_COMMIT_ID>
```

This will return the amount of files changed, insertions and deletions example:

```
25 files changed, 378 insertions(+), 373 deletions(-)
```